# Search by sku not working with solr in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, solr

solr search is integrated with magento-2. Itst working fine. But when product is searched by Valid SKU, results not found message is appearing.

Answer (score 1):

I used the below setting for the SKU attribute. Now it works for me.

if its Magento+Solr make sure:

1. SKU attribute Properties has "Visible in Advanced Search" set to Yes
2. Clear cache and do re-indexing.